# Why is elevated homocysteine considered a risk factor for angina?

Tags: cardiology, homocysteine

Elevated homocysteine levels are listed among risk factors for angina. How is homocysteine related to the heart? Or the coronary arteries? How do these relationships make it a risk factor for angina? 
[image]

Comment: In [his answer to a related question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/8333/1413) Alan Boyd has given the mechanism how homocysteine inhibited (1)Protein C activation and the (2)binding of free thrombin, both ways promoting coagulation and thrombosis. According to the [answer of Xaqron below](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/8300/1413) there are further mechanisms. Not all of them are linked to angina yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Homocysteine**:

1. Causes endothelial dysfunction and damage
2. Accelerates thrombin formation
3. Inhibits native thrombolysis
4. Promotes lipid peroxidation through free radical formation
5. Induces vascular smooth muscle proliferation
6. Promotes monocyte chemotaxis

Many observational epidemiological studies indicate that individuals with higher **Homocysteine** levels have increased risks of cardiovascular disease.

Comment: How can the effects on _lipid peroxidation_, _smooth muscle proliferation_ and _monocytes_ lead to angina?

Comment: Did you mean thrombUS formation (rather than thrombIN)?

Comment: @winerd: No, if it accelerates thrombus formation then it would be more dangerous. I meant `thrombin` formation as already said in answer.

Comment: I guess that the effects on _endothel_, _thrombin_ and _thrombolysis_ may contribute to coronary thrombus formation, and that's the link towards angina. Am I right?

Comment: @winerd: Mechanism is unknown at the time but these factors make a good basis for thrombus formation. Your questions are more medical than biologic, consider voting on `Medicine` in [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45132/medicine)

Comment: @Xaqron I'd say this is on topic for us.  I can see how the factors you've listed would be clear risk factors for myocardial infarction but, with the possible exception of 5, I'm not seeing a clear link to Angina (stable or otherwise).  Could you elaborate further?

Comment: @RoryM: Smooth muscle proliferation => lower internal diameter of vessels.

Comment: Citing a reference for this would make for a slightly stronger answer as well, just a suggestion, though.

Comment: @Xaqron: RoryM mentioned 'smooth muscle proliferation' as the one where (s)he sees a link, not where (s)he does not.